# Store Mysql coulmn names in array using Python mysql connector

Tags: python, mysql, arrays, mysql-connector-python

I'm quite new to mysql as in manipulating the database itself. I succeeded to store new lines in a table but my next endeavor will be a little more complex.

I'd like to fetch the column names from an existing mysql database and save them to an array in python. I'm using the official mysql connector.

I'm thinking I can achieve this through the information_schema.columns command but I have no idea how to build the query and store the information in an array. It will be around 100-200 columns so performance might become an issue so I don't think its wise just to iterate my way through it for each column.

The base code to inject code into mysql using the connector is:

```
def insert(data):
    query = "INSERT INTO templog(data) " \
        "VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
    args = (data)

try:
    db_config = read_db_config()
    conn = MySQLConnection(db_config)

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query, args)

    #if cursor.lastrowid:
     #   print('last insert id', cursor.lastrowid)
    #else:
     #   print('last insert id not found')

    conn.commit()

    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
except Error as error:
    print(error)
```

As said this above code needs to be modified in order to get data from the sql server. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use **ORM** like **SQLAlchemy**.

Comment: Hi andy, so it would be something like this then?

`#get all names from the database
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine

    connection = create_engine('mysql://user:passwd@localhost:3306/db').connect()

    result = connection.execute("select * from table")
    for v in result:
        for column, value in v.items():
            print('{0}: {1}'.format(column, value))`

Comment: right good move

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help!

Got this as working code:

```
def GetNames(web_data, counter):
#get all names from the database
connection = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://user:pwd@server:3306/db').connect()
result = connection.execute('select * from price_usd')
a = 0
sql_matrix = [0 for x in range(counter + 1)]
for v in result:
    while a == 0:
        for column, value in v.items():
            a = a + 1
            if a > 1: 
                sql_matrix[a] = str(('{0}'.format(column)))
```

This will get all column names from the existing sql database